# spark-submit command fails to connect to spark node for bluemix analytics engine service

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud, spark-submit, analytics-engine

I am trying to deploy spark application (Java) to spark engine as part of analytics engine service on Bluemix. I followed the step mention here

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/AnalyticsEngine/WCE-CLI.html#analytics-engine-command-line-interface

After following all the steps and at the time of spark-submit, i get the following error

```
C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\eclipse-workspace\mySparkApp\target>bx ae spark-submit --className mySparkApp.Main mySparkApp-0.0.1-S
NAPSHOT.jar
Current user is 'clsadmin'
Password>
Contacting endpoint 'https://159.122.220.119:8443'...
FAILED
Server call failed. Message: '<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /gateway/default/livy/v1/batches. Reason:
<pre>    Server Error</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>

</body>
</html>
'
```

I am able to access the ambari server and can see the spark services up and running. I am also able to access the livy API endpoint from the browser

https://chs-uvi-769-mn001.bi.services.eu-gb.bluemix.net:8443/gateway/default/livy/v1/batches

```
{"from":0,"total":5,"sessions":[{"id":0,"state":"dead","appId":null,"appInfo":{"driverLogUrl":null,"sparkUiUrl":null},"log":["java.lang.Exception: No YARN application is found with tag livy-batch-0-t8fc4ebv in 60 seconds. Please check your cluster status, it is may be very busy.","com.cloudera.livy.utils.SparkYarnApp.com$cloudera$livy$utils$SparkYarnApp$$getAppIdFromTag(SparkYarnApp.scala:182) com.cloudera.livy.utils.SparkYarnApp$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkYarnApp.scala:248) com.cloudera.livy.utils.SparkYarnApp$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkYarnApp.scala:245) scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) com.cloudera.livy.utils.SparkYarnApp$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkYarnApp.scala:245) com.cloudera.livy.Utils$$anon$1.run(Utils.scala:95)"]},{"id":1,"state":"dead","appId":null,"appInfo":{"driverLogUrl":null,"sparkUiUrl":null},"log":["java.lang.Exception: No YARN application is found with tag livy-batch-1-1olxdmt5 in 60 seconds. Please check your cluster status, it is may be very busy.","com.cloudera.livy.utils.SparkYarnApp.com$cloudera$livy$utils$SparkYarnApp$$getAppIdFromTag(SparkYarnApp.scala:182) com.cloudera.livy.utils.SparkYarnApp$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkYarnApp.scala:248) com.cloudera.livy.utils.SparkYarnApp$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkYarnApp.scala:245) scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) com.cloudera.livy.utils.SparkYarnApp$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkYarnApp.scala:245) com.cloudera.livy.Utils$$anon$1.run(Utils.scala:95)"]},{"id":2,"state":"dead","appId":null,"appInfo":{"driverLogUrl":null,"sparkUiUrl":null},"log":["java.lang.Exception: No YARN application is found with tag livy-batch-2-xbjzpkbp in 60 seconds. Please check your cluster status, it is may be very busy.","com.cloudera.livy.utils.SparkYarnApp.com$cloudera$livy$utils$SparkYarnApp$$getAppIdFromTag(SparkYarnApp.scala:182) com.cloudera.livy.utils.SparkYarnApp$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkYarnApp.scala:248) com.cloudera.livy.utils.SparkYarnApp$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkYarnApp.scala:245) scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) com.cloudera.livy.utils.SparkYarnApp$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkYarnApp.scala:245) com.cloudera.livy.Utils$$anon$1.run(Utils.scala:95)"]},{"id":3,"state":"dead","appId":null,"appInfo":{"driverLogUrl":null,"sparkUiUrl":null},"log":["java.lang.Exception: No YARN application is found with tag livy-batch-3-sbilpm4a in 60 seconds. Please check your cluster status, it is may be very busy.","com.cloudera.livy.utils.SparkYarnApp.com$cloudera$livy$utils$SparkYarnApp$$getAppIdFromTag(SparkYarnApp.scala:182) com.cloudera.livy.utils.SparkYarnApp$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkYarnApp.scala:248) com.cloudera.livy.utils.SparkYarnApp$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkYarnApp.scala:245) scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) com.cloudera.livy.utils.SparkYarnApp$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkYarnApp.scala:245) com.cloudera.livy.Utils$$anon$1.run(Utils.scala:95)"]},{"id":4,"state":"dead","appId":null,"appInfo":{"driverLogUrl":null,"sparkUiUrl":null},"log":["java.lang.Exception: No YARN application is found with tag livy-batch-4-rvlzpl8o in 60 seconds. Please check your cluster status, it is may be very busy.","com.cloudera.livy.utils.SparkYarnApp.com$cloudera$livy$utils$SparkYarnApp$$getAppIdFromTag(SparkYarnApp.scala:182) com.cloudera.livy.utils.SparkYarnApp$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkYarnApp.scala:248) com.cloudera.livy.utils.SparkYarnApp$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkYarnApp.scala:245) scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) com.cloudera.livy.utils.SparkYarnApp$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkYarnApp.scala:245) com.cloudera.livy.Utils$$anon$1.run(Utils.scala:95)"]}]}
```

I am not able to get what is the issue. I have enabled the bluemix trace and the output in debug mode for the same command is

```
C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\eclipse-workspace\mySparkApp\target>SET BLUEMIX_TRACE=true

C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\eclipse-workspace\mySparkApp\target>bx ae spark-submit --className mySparkApp.Main mySparkApp-0.0.1-S
NAPSHOT.jar
Current user is 'clsadmin'
Password>
DEBUG: INPUTS PROVIDED

 file mySparkApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
 proxyUser NOTSET
 className mySparkApp.Main
 inputArgs []
 jars []
 pyFiles []
 files []
 driverMemory NOTSET
 driverCores -1
 executorMemory NOTSET
 executorCores -1
 numExecutors -1
 archives []
 queue NOTSET
 name NOTSET
 conf map[]
 asynchronous false
 upload false

DEBUG: PROCESSED INPUTS

 file mySparkApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
 proxyUser NOTSET
 className mySparkApp.Main
 inputArgs []
 jars []
 pyFiles []
 files []
 driverMemory NOTSET
 driverCores -1
 executorMemory NOTSET
 executorCores -1
 numExecutors -1
 archives []
 queue NOTSET
 name NOTSET
 conf map[]
 asynchronous false
 upload false

Contacting endpoint 'https://159.122.220.119:8443'...

←[1;39mREQUEST:←[0m [2018-05-03T16:52:33+05:30]
POST /gateway/default/livy/v1/batches HTTP/1.1
Host: 159.122.220.119:8443
Accept: application/json
Authorization: [PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN]
Content-Type: application/json
X-Requested-By: livy

{"file":"mySparkApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar","className":"mySparkApp.Main"}

←[1;39mRESPONSE:←[0m [2018-05-03T16:52:34+05:30] ←[1;39mElapsed:←[0m 1382ms
HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
Connection: close
Content-Length: 321
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Date: Thu, 03 May 2018 11:22:52 GMT
Date: Thu, 03 May 2018 11:22:52 GMT
Server: Jetty(9.2.16.v20160414)
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=vyw2g1lyyjmo2d2spzs5pnd1;Path=/gateway/default;Secure;HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: rememberMe=deleteMe; Path=/gateway/default; Max-Age=0; Expires=Wed, 02-May-2018 11:22:52 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /gateway/default/livy/v1/batches. Reason:
<pre>    Server Error</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>

</body>
</html>

FAILED
Server call failed. Message: '<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /gateway/default/livy/v1/batches. Reason:
<pre>    Server Error</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>

</body>
</html>
'

FAILED
Server call failed. Message: '←[1;31m<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /gateway/default/livy/v1/batches. Reason:
<pre>    Server Error</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>

</body>
</html>
←[0m'
```

Can anyone see what is the issue ? any help or pointer ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, I have noticed this error when there is an issue with the program. If you have access to the cluster i.e. ssh clsadmin@ , you can try running the java program using spark-submit and confirm that the program is valid and there is no issue.

Comment: I think application local to the spark engine runs fine but my understanding is that I should be able to submit the application jar from a remote machine using AE client plugin of bluemix.

Answer (score 0):

1) Could you please check the Livy log on the spark node (/var/log/livy2) for any error messages logged there?
2) You can also try restarting Livy service on your cluster?

On our test server able to run the sample code:

`bx ae spark-submit --className org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi   local:/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/jars/spark-examples.jar
    User (clsadmin)> 
    Password> 
   Contacting endpoint 'https://169.60.167.93:8443'...
   Job ID '8'
   Waiting for job to return application ID. Will check every 10 seconds,    and stop checking after 2 minutes. Press Control C to stop waiting.
Finished contacting endpoint 'https://169.60.167.93:8443'
   OK
  Job ID '8'
   Application ID 'application_1521738019714_0083'
   Done`

Comment: I am able to run the sample code, however my own code does not work due to the mention error. The only difference i see is that the application in sample case is local to the spark node, while for me I am submitting the jar file from my local system.